# How to use UIBezierPath to draw multiple rectangle cutouts on top of one mask

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I am trying to create one mask with tree rectangle cutouts. Is it possible to do so with the `UIBezierPath` library?

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0;i<3;i++)
{
    NSDictionary *Def = [self.coachMarks objectAtIndex:i];
    CGRect Rect = [[markDef objectForKey:@"rect"] CGRectValue];

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    UIBezierPath *cutoutPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:markRect cornerRadius:self.cutoutRadius];
    [maskPath appendPath:cutoutPath];
    mask.path = maskPath.CGPath;
}
```

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: I know, I figured below is what I wrote.

Comment: take a look at my coachmark library, in PICoachmarkView.m (https://github.com/phamquy/PICoachmark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rearranged the entire library and this is the main method I had to change to be able to draw multiple rect shapes on top of a layer mask anywhere you specify on the screen. To initialize the coordinates you need to create an array and call it coachMarks. This applies to my example.

```
- (void)goToCoachMarkIndexed:(NSUInteger)index {

    markIndex = index;

    NSMutableArray *aBezierPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0;i<self.coachMarks.count;i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *markDef = [self.coachMarks objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect markRect = [[markDef objectForKey:@"rect"] CGRectValue];  
        [aBezierPaths addObject:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:markRect cornerRadius:self.cutoutRadius]];
    }
    for(NSUInteger i = 0;i<self.coachMarks.count;i++)
    {
        [maskPath appendPath:[aBezierPaths objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    mask.path = maskPath.CGPath;
}
```